# R character Encoding goes wrong (English - Spanish)

Tags: r, character-encoding

Im trying to load a dataset into R using an API that lets me do a query and returns back the data I need (I cant configure on server side).

I know it has something to do with Encoding. When i check the string in from by dataframe in R in gives me ENC: `UTF-8` "CosmÃ©tica".

When i copy the source string "Cosmética" it gives me `latin1.`

How can i get the UTF-8 string properly formatted like the latin1? 
 Ive tried this below:

`Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","Spanish")`

tried directly on the string:

`Enconding(Description) <- "latin1"`

unfortunately i cant get it to work. Any ideas are welcome! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `iconv` to change to encoding of the string:

```
iconv(mystring, to = "ISO-8859-1")
# [1] "Cosmética"
```

ISO 8859-1 is the common character encoding in Western Europe.

Comment: thanks for this. It works indeed if the source Encoding is correct. For me some system setting were overwritten so i changed those and works now ;-)